# How to download file on client machine using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

Am trying to download a file on the client's machine. Am not trying to do it without client's knowledge. The file is already stored on the server. I have the file path and i have tried the method below. But it doesn't seem to work. Am using current version of Google Chrome. And it keeps failing.

```
try{
            string Filpath = ParseRequest.GetFileDetails(fileId);
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Filpath);
            string fileLength = file.Length.ToString();
            string fileName = file.Name;
            string fullName = file.FullName;                
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.ClearContent();                    
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";                   
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileLength);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);                  
                Response.Write(fullName);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();
            }else{
                Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            XLog.Error(ex);
        }
```

Below is the screenshot of the response i get:
[image]

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" isn't enough to help us help you diagnose this. Is there an exception thrown? Is there an error logged? Does it work in other browsers? Have you debugged this by setting breakpoints and watching what the code is doing?

Comment: you can't do a drive by download. thats incredibly poor taste.

Comment: For a PDF you need `Response.BinaryWrite()` and `Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";` (or simply `.WriteFile()`)

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ By mentioning that it "doesnt seem to work", I meant that the i get the response, but its like a parsed PDF garbage value string when i check the response on the "developer tool" (pressing F12).

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you elaborate on the "drive by download" please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download

Comment: @AlexK. I will try that and check.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks.

Comment: @DanielA.White I actually use this method after the user  clicks on the "Download File". Like i mentioned in the question, it is not without user's knowledge.

Comment: Are you trying to do this behind an AJAX call? You shouldn't -- browse to your download action just like any other page -- the content-disposition header will tell your browser to show the download dialog and not actually redirect your page.

Comment: @AlexK. It doesnt work. I have edited the question to include the response i get. Hope that helps

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Yes, I call the "GetFile" method using Ajax call when user clicks on "Download File". Do you mean that I shouldnt do that?

Comment: For security reasons your browser will not serve files like that when behind an AJAX request. Simply do a `window.location = url;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to invoke a file download (via the `content-dispostion: attachment` header) behind an AJAX request. Browsers don't allow this for obvious security reasons. So, instead, simply navigate to the URL that invokes the download action on the server instead of trying to grab the result of the AJAX request.

```
window.location = "path/to/downloadaction.aspx/GetFile/?fileId=xxx";
```

The headers you have specified will instruct the browser to make the request, but instead of executing a response that redirects to a page, the browser will show the file download dialog and leave you on the page where the button was clicked.

If you need to POST data in order to perform the file download request, you could use an embedded `<iframe>` -- unfortunately they can still workaround the AJAX file limitations.

**EDIT** Alex K. was right in the comments as well, you need to add the bytes of the file into the response via `Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes)` so you'll need a `File.ReadAllBytes()` in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did help!